# Firebase Cloud Functions with Cloud Firestore trouble

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I have used this Firebase Database code in a previous project:

```
const getDeviceUser = admin.database().ref(`/users/${notification.to}/`).once('value');
```

I am now trying to convert it for Firestore. I am basically trying to get my users fcm's when a notification is being sent. I have tried many things, but haven't seen the new way to accomplish this.

EDIT: here is my code.

```
exports.sendFavoriteNotification = functions.firestore.document('users/{userUid}/notifications/{notificationId}').onCreate(event => {
const notification = event.data.data();
const user = event.params.userUid;

const getDeviceUser = admin.database().ref(`/users/${notification.to}/`).once('value');

// Get the follower profile.
const getProfilePromise = admin.auth().getUser(notification.sender);

return Promise.all([getDeviceUser, getProfilePromise]).then(results => {
  const tokensSnapshot = results[0];
  const liker = results[1];

  // Check if there are any device tokens.
  if (!tokensSnapshot.hasChildren()) {
    return console.log('There are no notification tokens to send to.');
  }

  //console.log('There are', tokensSnapshot.numChildren(), 'tokens to send notifications to.');
  console.log('Fetched follower profile', liker);

  // Notification details.
  const payload = {
    notification : {
      title : 'You have a new like!',
      body : `${liker.displayName} just liked your photo.`,
      badge: '1',
      sound: 'default'
    }
  };

  // Listing all tokens.
  var tokens = admin.firestore.ref(`/users/${notification.to}/`).get('fcm');

  // Send notifications to all tokens.
  admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens.data(), payload);
  return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload).then(response => {
    // For each message check if there was an error.
    const tokensToRemove = [];
    response.results.forEach((result, index) => {
      const error = result.error;
      if (error) {
        console.error('Failure sending notification to', tokens[index], error);
        // Cleanup the tokens who are not registered anymore.
        if (error.code === 'messaging/invalid-registration-token' ||
            error.code === 'messaging/registration-token-not-registered') {
          tokensToRemove.push(tokensSnapshot.update({
            fcm: FieldValue.delete()
          }));
        }
      }
    });
    return Promise.all(tokensToRemove);
  });
});
```

});

Comment: Hey there--can you tell us more about your data model and code?

Comment: Yes everything else is working I just took the example that firebase provides for fcm notifications. Basically right now I just need to be able to retrieve the  fcms and then return them in the function so it sends the notification.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that everything else is working! Helping you, though, requires more information. What do your documents look like?

Comment: Ok I added my code. The fcm variables aren't working, but once I can get the data then I know how to fix that stuff.

Comment: My notification documents are random keys with fields for the meta data. I am trying to get the fcm from a collection in the users data where the fcm tokens are the document id.

Comment: Okay, what isn't working about this right now? Please provide as much context as you can.

Comment: So I need to be able to retrieve the users fcms, and I need to retrieve and store them in a variable before I return the function so I can send the notification to the right user devices. A synchronous database call would work but the usual asynchronous call with firebase makes it hard to call the server before it returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will help. This is my code after 2 days of trying to learn how to convert from realtime database to firestore. It is based on a firebase project: https://github.com/MahmoudAlyuDeen/FirebaseIM

```
let functions = require('firebase-functions');
let admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.sendNotificationToFirestone = functions.firestore.document('/notifications/{pushId}')
    .onCreate(event => {
        const pushId = event.data.id;
        const message = event.data.data();
        const senderUid = message.from;
        const receiverUid = message.to;
        const db = admin.firestore();

        if (senderUid === receiverUid) {
            console.log('pushId: '+ pushId);
            return db.collection('notifications').doc(pushId).delete();;
        } else {
            const ref = db.collection('users').doc(receiverUid);

            const query = new Promise(
                function (resolve, reject) {
                    ref.get()
                        .then(doc => {
                            if (!doc.exists) {
                                console.log('No such document!');
                                reject(new Error('No such document!'));

                            } else {
                                console.log('Document data:', doc.data().instanceId);
                                resolve(doc.data().instanceId);
                            }
                        })
                        .catch(err => {
                            console.log('Error getting document', err);
                            reject(err);
                        });
                });


            const getSenderUidPromise = admin.auth().getUser(senderUid);

            return Promise.all([query, getSenderUidPromise]).then(results => {
                //console.log('instanceId = Result[0]: ' + results[0]);
                //console.log('sender = Result[1]: ' + results[1]);
                const instanceId = results[0];
                const sender = results[1];
                //console.log('notifying ' + receiverUid + ' about ' + message.body + ' from ' + senderUid);
                //console.log('instanceId este' + instanceId);

                const payload = {
                    notification: {
                        title: sender.displayName,
                        body: message.body,
                        icon: sender.photoURL
                    }
                };

                admin.messaging().sendToDevice(instanceId, payload)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        console.log("Message sent: ", response);
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log("Error sending message: ", error);
                    });
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: I had to change a couple things, because I am using multiple fcm tokens per user incase they have many devices, but this does work!